# How to solved : [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected: '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/superpixels/MNIST.pkl'

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, neural-network, dataset

I am still confused about how to solve this program error, even though the accessed file is already in the directory

`DATASET_NAME = 'MNIST' dataset = LoadData(DATASET_NAME) # 54s trainset, valset, testset = dataset.train, dataset.val, dataset.testt`

i'm having trouble running the section

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.